# Browser Detection in the Post-Conditional Comment Age?

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer, browser-detection

Internet Explorer 10+ no longer supports conditional comments. Alright, awesome.

Here's what I need:

```
    (if this browser is Internet Explorer of ANY version) {
         //apply IE CSS class here
    } else {
         //apply non IE CSS class here
    }
```

I've tried everything I could find on the interwebs, and nothing works where it doesn't affect ALL browsers. The follow code, for example does not work, as "Browser is nott IE is printed on all browsers:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <!--[if lte IE 8]><html class="ie8 no-js" lang="en">IE 8-10<![endif]-->
    <!--[if lte IE 10]><html class="ie10 no-js" lang="en">ID 8-<![endif]-->
    <script>
    var isIE = (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1);
    if (!isIE) {
    document.write("<html class='not-ie no-js' lang='en'>");
    document.write("Browser is nott IE.");
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: The post-conditional comment age favors feature detection over browser detection.

Comment: Whoever marked this as a duplicate was wrong. The answer you connected this one to is also deprecated. $.browser does not work for Jquery 1.9+.

Comment: Yes, the accepted answer is deprecated and should be disregarded. What about any of the 20+ other answers to that question? How is your question different, unless you're asking for a solution for each browser family (which does not appear to be the case since it's focused on IE)?

Comment: It's different because none of them WORK, or take a lot of code for something very simple, or (and especially) care about version #. I don't care about version #. I simply wanted a check for if (a BOOLEAN) the browser used is IE. I found a solution that works that deals with the navigator.userAgent header string and checks for if it contains .NET.

Comment: Fair enough - so the difference here is that you don't care about version #. I'll unmark.

Comment: I remember `<!--[if !IE]><!-->Embed CSS here<!--<![endif]-->` working for me in IE 11.. For some strange reason with the extra `<!-->`

Comment: @areyoujokingme You can do: `var isie = !~"\v0";`. It gives `true` in ie; it doesn't strip vertical tab..

Comment: Two answers were given in the meantime (July 4, 2014). Any response?

Answer (score 1):

```
navigator.sayswho= (function(){
    var ua= navigator.userAgent, tem, 
    M= ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || [];
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=  /\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || [];
        return 'IE '+(tem[1] || '');
    }
    if(M[1]=== 'Chrome'){
        tem= ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
        if(tem!= null) return 'Opera '+tem[1];
    }
    M= M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem= ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!= null) M.splice(1, 1, tem[1]);
    return M.join(' ');
})();
```

The code will return the name of your browser. You can execute conditional statements based off of the return value.

Thanks to u/kennebec for the script. Works great.

Answer (score 1):

While feature detection is often the most economical way way to tell supportive from non-supportive browser versions, detecting IE -- and its versions -- is actually a piece of cake:

```
var uA = navigator.userAgent;
var browser = null;
var ieVersion = null;
var htmlTag = document.documentElement;

if (uA.indexOf('MSIE 6') >= 0) {
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = 6;
}
if (uA.indexOf('MSIE 7') >= 0) {
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = 7;
}
if (document.documentMode) { // as of IE8; strictly IE proprietary 
    browser = 'IE';
    ieVersion = document.documentMode;
}

// Using it can be done like this: 
if (browser == 'IE' && ieVersion == 11)
    htmlTag.className += ' ie11';
```

One is catching higher IEs in lower Modes/Views as well with this script, including Compatibility ~. I included the version parts, because any serious web developer will sooner or later come across IE version differences.